# error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: Error 40

Tags: libraries

There is an application I want to use named openfoam but, I can't because of this error.
I already tried other way but none of them work.

The command I tipped was:

```
-> fluent3DMeshToFoam Test.obj

fluent3DMeshToFoam: error while loading shared libraries: libmeshTools.so: cannot open shared object file: Error 40


-> sudo find -name "libmeshTools.so"

./usr/lib64/libmeshTools.so
./usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2206/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libmeshTools.so
./usr/lib/libmeshTools.so


-> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/usr/lib/
```

and I already tried `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v`

So I know the library is on the disk, the library path is right and I already created new links. Is there anything I am missing?

Edit:

```
-> ldd fluent3DMeshToFoam
ldd: ./fluent3DMeshToFoam: No such file or directory

-> file libmeshTools.so
libmeshTools.so: cannot open `libmeshTools.so' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Can you run a few commands and edit your question with the results? Try `ldd fluent3DMeshToFoam` along with the results of running `file` on each of the libraries.

Comment: you need to source in the openfoam env file, as the library needs libraries to work. 
 https://openfoam.org/download/source/setting-environment/ . on ubuntu `. /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2206/etc/bashrc` works for me.

Comment: I am guessing given the `sudo find` that you have installed this software under `/root` in which case `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is missing `/root/usr/lib/` or you are missing the corresponding entry under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.